# How to attach multiple Images with a note taking app in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to make a note taking app in android and i am done with simple note text saving part. Now, i'm trying to attach images with note (in edittext). I tried spannable to implement this thing but not able to handle different events like deleting image.

Can anyone help me that how i can attach images with notes and show them in an EditText?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got the solution for this problem and now my code is working perfectly as i wanted in my android app.

This was the code that i used to add/draw images in EditText in android and then read the touch event on them.

```
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_document);
final Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), b);
d.setBounds(0, 0, 200, 200);
final ImageSpan is = new ImageSpan(d);

SpannableStringBuilder ss = new SpannableStringBuilder(".\n");
ss.setSpan(is, 0, (".\n").length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
ss.setSpan(new MyClickAbleSpan("abc"), 0, (".\n").length(), 0);
editor.append(ss, 0, (".\n").length());
editor.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

And this is MyClickAbleSpan class:-

```
class MyClickAbleSpan extends ClickableSpan {

    String filePath;

    public MyClickAbleSpan(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        Toast.makeText(SpannableActivity.this, filePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```